# REST API - Save data from other endpoints in one controller

Tags: php, rest

I have two API endpoints, `Person` and `Domain`. Each of them has an own controller, used to handle `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` requests.

Now, a `domain` has to be assigned to a `person`, so what I thought was the following. When adding a `Person` the user can send JSON to the REST API containing an `URL` which will be saved as a new `Domain`.

This is just a simple example. In the real life example, I have many other endpoints like `FacebookAccount`, `LinkedInAccount`, `GooglePlusAccount` etc.

My main question is: Is it a good practice, to allow the API user to add data to multiple `Endpoints/Ressources` in one request? Because, what I see as a problem is the following:

I don't want the user to do 10 requests to add a person with all his data like his domains, Facebook accounts etc. if he has multiple.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do two requests if you can do it in one. It would be like doing two car trips to drop two things off at the same place, when you could have just taken both of them in the car with you at once.

Just add the `{domain_id}` to your POST data when you call `POST /persons`

Comment: Hi, the problem I have is not, that I need to know how to do it. The problem I have is, the question if it is okay to add a domain, when adding a person, or if it should be seperated in multiple api requests

Comment: I'll just do the request like this `/person` and post data to be added as post data in json. Thanks for your answer. However, before I accept this one, I'll wait for another answer to be 100% sure

Comment: If `domain` is to be written, I'd put that in POST data, rather than a query string. But I agree that all items should be written at once - I don't see any point to splitting them up.